# c++ clang inline asm - undefined symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio, x86, clang, inline-assembly

I'm trying to access a global variable from inline assembly code but I get error "undefined symbol: my_var ":

```
#include <iostream>

int my_var = 0;

__attribute((naked)) int Test()
{
    asm(".intel_syntax noprefix;"
        "mov eax, my_var;"
        "ret;"
        ".att_syntax;"
    );
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << Test() << std::endl;
}
```

I'm using visual studio with LLVM (Clang-cl) compiler. I also tried with _my_var but same output. Using at&t syntax is not an option.

Comment: Works well https://godbolt.org/z/Eq3zbE7d1

Comment: @273K adding extern "C" to the variable fixed it, but if instead of my_var, I want to use a function like MessageBoxA I have the same issue as before. Any way to fix this?

Comment: You must link the app with User32.lib.

Comment: @273K user32.lib is already linked. I double checked adding #pragma comment (lib, "User32.lib")

Comment: If the MessageBox is imported from a runtime DLL, it might actually be called `__imp_MessageBoxA`. Anyway, calling it from inline asembly is, at best, an academic exercise. Not something you would actually do for real. If you want to learn how to write assembly properly, you should do that as separate .asm files. Inline assembly has its very own set of odd rules, and is then also almost totally useless.

Comment: @BoP I get "undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) MessageBoxA" with __imp_MessageBoxA.I thought about using separate .asm file, but the function I'm coding needs to use c++ templates and macros, thats why Im doing it with inline asm.